# Game Titles are hard

Tags: word-choice, titles

I'm currently in the process of making a small game with my friends. We're all either programmers or graphic artists by nature and as a result we've come fairly quickly in the few weeks of development we've done so far.

The problem is, we haven't come up with an acceptable title so I'm hoping some of you will be able to assist.

The premise of the game is: there is a large crew stuck on a space station. Amidst the crew there are various dangerous entities such as undercover spies, syndicate operatives, aliens who spit acid and absorb humans for food. The only escape is through a timed Emergency Rescue Ship that comes very late. There is going to be huge customization, lots of details (roguelike levels of detail).

Any suggestions for titles? For starters, here was a couple of ours:
a) Beyond Reach
b) Beyond Reach, Beyond Redemption
c) Space Outpost 
d) Syndicates from beyond the stars
e) Research Outpost 
ultimately, several of them are pretty good, but they don't seem 'right'.

I understand that for this to qualify under the 'word-choice' section I have to do this:

Words to use(and synonyms): Station, outpost, isolated, monster, syndicate, space, stars

I'd love some feedback!

Comment: *Staying Alive*?

Comment: How's about, "Oh, ship!"

Comment: hey catija, I just changed it so it would qualify under the word-choice rules. They can't remove it now!

Comment: Oh and those two suggestions are actually good! Only problem with staying alive is I get the tune of Bee Gees or images of that movie with John Travolta stuck in my head.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure if I were you (*that the OP can't be closed*). But I am pulling for you.   :-)

Comment: Assuming that most of the game occurs before the rescue ship belatedly arrives, another option is to call it "Before the Rescue"—or maybe "Killing Time Before the Rescue."

Comment: "Next rescue at platform 3..."

Comment: What will the tone of the game be like? Flippant and self-aware? Tense and harrowing? That should be reflected in your title choice too.

Comment: This question has no connection, even vaguely, to this site. **It's unfortunate that people waste your time by commenting, etc, rather than just moving the question to a new worthy home**.  Boeg, considering asking on the excellent game development site, or writers, or worldbuilders, or all three. But, not here.

Comment: "In space no one can hear you scream"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because game titles _are_ off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

How about just naming the game "Escape"?

Answer (score 0):

Future Fleet: Isolated Outpost